# Add new table to an existing database and EDMX model using Code First approach

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ado.net, asp.net-identity, database-migration

I have a database , for that DB I just created `edmx` model using `ADO.NET`

Now I want to change that DB using `CodeFirst` approach . Also I'm using `Asp.Net Identity` membership.

I want to add `Person`, `Files` and `FilePaths` table

```
public abstract class Person
{
    ///other relevant properties

    public virtual ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FilePath> FilePaths { get; set; }
}
```

**File model**

```
public class File 
{
    public int FileId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
    public FileType FileType { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

**FilePath model**

```
public class FilePath
{
    public int FilePathId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public FileType FileType { get; set; }
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

so I started like following

1. added following connectionstring in `web.config`

   `<add name="ProjectContext" connectionString="Data Source=***.***.*.***;Initial Catalog=MYDB;Persist Security Info=true;User ID=**;Password=*** " providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`
2. then I created folder cal `DAL` then added context file

   [image]

   ```
   public class ProjectContext : DbContext
   {
      public DbSet<File> Files { get; set; }    
      public DbSet<FilePath> FilePaths { get; set;     
   }
   ```

then I'm stucking in next step which is

when I'm going to Add a new migration by typing the following into the Package Manager Console(PMC):

`add-migration Files`

I'm getting following error in Package Manager Console

> Creating a DbModelBuilder or writing the EDMX from a DbContext created
>   using Database First or Model First is not supported. EDMX can only be
>   obtained from a Code First DbContext created without using an existing
>   DbCompiledModel.

Actually I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/259/asp-net-mvc-5-with-ef-6-working-with-files)

Comment: Ha ve you run enable-migrations command ?

Comment: @CodeNotFound yes using following `Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName projectname.DAL.ProjectContext`
then getting this exception `Migrations have already been enabled in project ' projectname'. To overwrite the existing migrations configuration, use the -Force parameter.`

Comment: show us the COnfiguration.cs file ?

Comment: @CodeNotFound where is that located

Comment: In the migrations folder of your project

Comment: there are 2  `Configuration.cs` files in that folder one in `Migrations` folder and another one is `ProjectContext` folder (`ProjectContext` folder is inside `Migrations` folder ) , which one you prefer

Comment: Weird. Normally if you folow the tutorial correctly you must have just one folder Migrations with Configurations.cs and migrations files. 
I recommend you to restart the tuorial you are missign something.

Comment: shall I reset migration here ?

Comment: First => `enable-migrations -force`
Second => `add-migration Init`
Third => `update-database`

Comment: @CodeNotFound I deleted `_MigrationHistroy`  table in DB then Delete `MigrationFolder` in the project (reset migration) then I started with from scratch,   First => `Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName projectname.DAL.ProjectContext` then Second => `add-migration Files` , but then getting following warning `changes to your model when you scaffold the next migration. If you make additional changes to your model that you want to include in this migration, then you can re-scaffold it by running 'Add-Migration Files' again.`

Comment: @CodeNotFound this is the [Configuration.cs file](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/yrqe4)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103717/discussion-between-kez-and-codenotfound).

Comment: @CodeNotFound can I use this solution with ASP.NET Identity membership ? that Existing DB and Existing model that generated through `ADO.NET` ?